# Is this an OK proof to show that eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-transformations, spectral-theory

Just a quick check: I'm not very good at proofs so I was seeing if this was correct:
Let $A$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ be the eigenvalues corresponding to the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ respectively. (Previously shown that all eigenvalues are real).

Then we want to show that $\langle v_1 | v_2 \rangle = 0$.

Consider $$\langle v_1 | v_2 \rangle = \langle \frac{Av_1}{\lambda_1} | \frac{Av_2}{\lambda_2}\rangle \\ \\ = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}\langle Av_1|Av_2 \rangle \\ = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}\langle v_1|A^{\star}Av_2 \rangle \\ = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}\langle v_1|A\lambda_2 v_2 \rangle \\=\frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}\langle v_1|{\lambda_2}^2 v_2 \rangle\\ =\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 }\langle v_1|v_2 \rangle$$
and so we have
$$\lambda_1 \langle v_1 | v_2 \rangle = \lambda_2 \langle v_1 | v_2\rangle$$
hence the result follows as $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.
I'm not sure if this would cover the case when one of the eigenvalues are zero though....

Comment: Standard approach is $$\langle Av_1 | v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1 |A^* v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1 | Av_2 \rangle$$ and then using the eigenvector condition to show that $$(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)\langle v_1 | v_2 \rangle=0.$$

Comment: Cheers. Seems more straightforward than my one. Was mine okay though (as in, no flaws or holes in it)?

Comment: You implicitly assume that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\neq0$, which is not always the case.

Comment: One workaround in this finite dimensional case is to assume you have a smallest eigenvalue, say $r$. Then all eigenvalues of $A-(r-1)I$ will be nonnegative, you can solve the problem for $A-(r-1)I$ using your approach, and then translate the result back to $A$. This approach should only work for bounded operators, though.